# How long does a PhD take in the United States?

Tags: phd, united-states

How many years does it take to get a PhD in the USA?  What is the typical time to degree?  I heard a rumor it was five years.

Comment: If it is 4 or 5 years in other countries and one has to pay then where should one look to study...

Comment: It varies with field and school and background.  E.g., from BS to PhD in pure math at top schools 5 years is common.  For lower tier schools, 6 years is more common.  Do you have a field/situation in mind?

Comment: Well spotted @Kimball.  I did not think to search for "duration."

Answer (score 1):

For US PhD recipients in 2018, the median years between starting graduate school and earning a doctorate was 7.3.  Completing a PhD in five years has been done many times, but most PhD students will not do it and *five years is not typical.*

Statistics do not include PhD students who never receive a PhD.

There is large variation based on discipline and race:
https://ncses.nsf.gov/pubs/nsf20301/assets/data-tables/tables/nsf20301-tab031.pdf
https://ncses.nsf.gov/pubs/nsf20301/assets/data-tables/tables/nsf20301-tab032.pdf

Comment: This answer should provide or link to an explanation of the US PhD that in contrast to some European systems does not require you to have a Master's degree. The average time in Europe is probably similar but of course statistics will split it between Master's degree and PhD.

Comment: @Roland You want this question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly

Comment: No, readers of this answer want it.

Comment: Well, I've linked it now, so they've got it.  In any case, a portion of the people in the linked data do have masters degrees.

Comment: Note that the normality of integrated graduate programs is field depended. Not all fields operate this way.